# Como posso saber se a variável é um número inteiro em Python?

Tags: python, int

Como posso sabe se a variável é um número inteiro em Python?

Eu sei fazer isso em PHP:

```
is_int($variable); // bool(true)
```

Mas como posso fazer em Python?

Exemplo:

```
numero = 1 #é numero
nao_eh_numero = 'texto' # não é número
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Válido pra Python 2 e 3

#### Usando [**`isinstance`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Passar como primeiro parâmetro a variável que deseja validar e como segundo parâmetro o "tipo".

Exemplo:

```
isinstance(numero, int) # True
```

**Observação**

Se você pretende validar se a variável **é um número**, usando Python 2. Precisará mudar o segundo parâmetro para `(int, long)`, no Python 3 isso não é necessário porque não existe `long`.

```
isinstance(numero, (int, long))
```

#### Usando [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

```
type(numero) == int # True
```

A diferença entre os dois é que `isinstance` também valida se o objeto é derivado da classe (uma classe filha). Ou seja, ele verifica toda a estrutura de herança do objeto. Já o `type` devolve apenas o tipo **exato**.

Exemplo para ilustrar

```
class MinhaClasseInt(int):
    pass

x = MinhaClasseInt(0)

type(x) == int # False
isinstance(x, int) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei essa formula aqui que fica mais fácil e dá o valor exato. Sem precisar se preocupar com o código considerar o (type)!
como:

```
x1 = float(input('Valor = '))
print(x1, type(x1))
def valor(v):
  n = int(v)
  m = v * 10
  s = n * 10
  if m == s:
    return ('O número {} é inteiro'.format(v))#retorn 1
  else:
    return ('O número {} é decimal'.format(v))#retorn 2 
r = valor(x1)
print(r)
```

Esse ai tem como vc mudar o (return) ou diminuir e ele vai verificar se o valor é inteiro ou decimal (float "flutuante"])

Você também pode testar o código e o resultado com esse aqui:

```
import os
while True:
  x1 = float(input('Valor = '))
  print(x1, type(x1))
  def valor(v):
    n = int(v)
    m = v * 10
    s = n * 10
    if m == s:
      return ('O número {} é inteiro'.format(v))#retorn 1
    else:
      return ('O número {} é decimal'.format(v))#retorn 2 
  r = valor(x1)
  print(r)
  p = input('RECOMEÇAR ! Aperte [ENTER]')
  os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Mas o básico é isto:

```
def valor(v):
    n = int(v)
    m = v * 10
    s = n * 10
    if m == s:
      return ('O número {} é inteiro'.format(v))#retorn 1
    else:
      return ('O número {} é decimal'.format(v))#retorn 2
```

Na parte de retornar tem (#reorn 1) or (#retorn 2). É para ficar mais facil de lidar com os resultados e fazer tipo assim:

```
def valor(v):
  n = int(v)
  m = v * 10
  s = n * 10
  if m == s:
    return 1
  else:
    return 2 
while True:
  n = float(input('valor = '))
  r = valor(n)
  #Agora vc pode brincar
  if r == 1:
    print('Você digitou um numero INTEIRO se imbecil !')
  elif r == 2: # Ou vc pode usar [ELSE]
    print('Você digitou um numero DECIMAL seu aderbal !')
```

Ai fica mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Eu faria diferente e de forma mais fácil.
Faça assim:

```
numero = float(input('Digite um numero qualquer :'))

if(numero // 1 == numero): 
    print('\nNúmero inteiro !')
else:
    print('\nNúmero Decimal !')
```

Perceba que número 1 retorna somente a parte inteira; logo, se essa divisão retornar o próprio número então se trata de um inteiro.

Comment: É a mesma coisa que o Guilherme BL respondeu: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/228700/3635

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade esse // nem precisa ser feito, apenas perguntar:

```
if int(numero) == numero:
```

Comment: Mas a outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176529/8063) já disse isso. :/

Answer (score -3):

Mas usando tanto o `type` quanto o `isinstance`, se o conteúdo da variável for digitado com um ponto decimal (12.0, por exemplo), a variável será um `float` e o resultado da expressão será `False`, mesmo o número sendo inteiro.

Acho que esta resposta fica melhor:

```
if numero // 1 = numero: # se for True o número é inteiro
```

Isso funciona mesmo se for uma variável tipo `float`.

Comment: Se é um float, não é um inteiro. Matematicamente eles até podem ser equivalentes, mas computacionalmente não. O tipo float exige uma representação diferente, geralmente seguindo o padrão definido na IEEE 754.

Comment: Sim, a resposta computacional é com o código acima.
Mas eu quis aprimorar e pensar em uma resposta para a questão matemática.

Answer (score -5):

```
def int_float(num):

  if num.isnumeric():
     num = int(num)
     return num


  elif num.replace(".", "").isnumeric():
     num = float(num)
     return num
  else:
     return num # é string
```

**OBS:**

- `.replace(".", "")` - TROCA O PONTO do decimal POR NADA
- `.isnumeric()` - Confirma se é número

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Samuel, não use as edições para descaracterizar as respostas. Mesmo que não concorde com o conteúdo respeite o que o autor quis dizer, a finalidade das edições é melhorar a leitura e apresentação visual da publicação. Para indicar a comunidade que uma publicação é de baixa qualidade você pode [a sinalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) e também pode usar o nosso [sistema de votação em conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).