# Identificar se o valor que está sendo impresso é do tipo float, string ou int

Tags: python

No python é possível fazer uma impressão de vários tipos de variáveis usando o `print`. Vejam um exemplo:

```
print(3.4, "hello", 45);
```

Ou individualmente.

```
print(3.4);
print("hello");
print(45);
```

Como é possível identificar se o valor que está sendo impresso é do tipo `float`, `string` ou `int`?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como posso saber se a variável é um número inteiro em Python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176525/18246)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para sabermos o tipo/classe podemos fazer ([type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)):

```
print(type(3.4), type("hello"), type(45)) # <class 'float'> <class 'str'> <class 'int'>
```

Para filtrar somente o a parte do `float`, `str`, `int` podes:

```
print(type(3.4).__name__, type("hello").__name__, type(45).__name__) # float str int
```

Para verificações podes usar e é mais direto [isinstance(var, (objs,))](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(3.4, float):
    # True, e float
```

Podes inclusive verificar se pertence a algum dos vários tipos/classes que entram como argumento dentro de um tuple:

```
if isinstance(3.4, (float, str)):
    # True, e float ou string
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [**`type`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

```
print(type(3.4), type("hello"), type(45))

>> <class 'float'> <class 'str'> <class 'int'>
```