# Qual diferença entre type e dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

Baseado em [uma pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192161/35406), vi que é possível fazer a identificação de uma variável usando `type`. Como por exemplo:

```
print(type(3.1415).__name__) #retorno >> float
```

Fazendo umas pesquisas, vi que existe o `dtype`. Qual diferença entre `type` e `dtype`? Em que situação devo usar o `dtype`?

Comment: Cara, `dtype` é coisa do numpy.

Comment: Mas é python não é?! Foi de relance eu vi algo como `dtype('float64')`, e não entendi... achei que era algo relacionado.

Comment: @AckLay: ficou alguma dúvida ainda? Quer mais algum exemplo na resposta?

Comment: @jsbueno nenhuma dúvida. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` é um nome embutido da linguagem Python - é uma chamada que ou identifica o tipo de um objeto, ou cria um tipo novo.

`dtype` é o nome de um parâmetro/membro de objetos da biblioteca numérica numpy. Embora o numpy seja muito popular, não se pode confundi-lo com o núcleo da linguagem - nem `dtype` é universal - mesmo no numpy é um atributo ou parâmetro que só estará presente onde fizer sentido.

`dtype` é a abreviação de  `data type`e é usado no numpy e biblitoecas numéricas/científicas correlatas para identificar o tipo de dados que estará contido num objeto.

Esse tipo de dados faz sentido para cálculo numérico e pode ou não ter uma correspondência direta para um tipo de dados nativo do Python.

Por exemplo, uma variável `x = 1` tem um número em Python, `type(x)` vai te retornar "int".  Mas não existe `dtype(x)` ou `x.dtype`. Agora:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.zeros((1000,))
```

permite que se faça `y.dtype` e a resposta padrão é "float64" - que indica que cada número dentro do array "y" é um número floating point de 64bit. Poder especificar o dtype no caso das estruturas numpy permite que o desenvolvedor tenha controle sobre o tipo de dados e consumo de memória com que está trabalhando - poderia ser "float32", para menor precisão e consumo metade da memória, poderia ser "uint8" se o seu problema envolver imagens preto e branco e todos os dados tiverem apenas um byte.

Já no núcleo linguagem Python, devido à natureza dinâmica, não faz sentido detalhar como um número será armazenado. Em python3, por exemplo, a linguagem determina dinamicamente se o valor de um objeto do tipo "int"  será um inteiro nativo da máquina, ou mantido como uma string que permite um número indeterminado de casas decimais - e quem está usando o número nem vai ficar sabendo.

Além disso, cabe adicionar que os tipos de dados identificados pelo "dtype" são strings, que são usadas como constantes - enquanto que os retornados pelo "type" sempre são classes de Python. (Uma classe tem o atributo  `__name__` que você usou na questão - retorna o nome da classe como uma string)