# Aplanar lista de listas. É possível uma solução mais concisa?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Resolvi o seguinte exercício de Python:

> Implementar uma função que receba uma lista de listas de comprimentos
>   quaisquer e retorne uma lista de uma dimensão.

A solução que consegui fazer foi a seguinte:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def list_unifier(lista_de_listas):
    lista_unificada = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista_de_listas)):
        for j in range(0, len(lista_de_listas[i])):
            lista_unificada.append(lista_de_listas[i][j])

    return lista_unificada

print list_unifier([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7]])
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

A pergunta é, esta seria a melhor maneira de fazer? Achei meio prolixa.

Estava pensando em algo envolvendo `for i in lista_de_listas` ou algo assim.

Comment: Vários exemplos aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @bruno Faltou especificar na pergunta mas seria algo sem nenhum recurso avançado, somente controle de fluxo básico. Ainda estou no ABC da linguagem. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma ideia que encurta o seu código sem chamar pacotes adicionais é:

```
def list_unifier(lista_de_listas):
    lista_unificada = []
    for lista in lista_de_listas:
        for elemento in lista:
            lista_unificada.append(elemento)
    return lista_unificada
```

Chamando a função:

```
print(list_unifier([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7]])) # Sintaxe válida para Python 3 ou 2 
print list_unifier([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7]]) # Sintaxe válida apenas para Python 2
```

Resultado:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Eu renomeei os iteradores de cada `for loop` para ficar mais fácil de entender. Primeiramente usamos um `for` para selecionar cada lista na lista de listas. Em seguida, usamos um segundo `for` para pegar cada elemento na lista selecionada.
Como selecionamos o elemento e não a sua posição, não precisamos usar índices para fazer o `append`, basta chamar `lista_unificada.append(elemento)`.

Comment: Era isto que eu estava procurando! Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Ao estilo de [*antigravity*](https://xkcd.com/353/) e, de modo geral, mais *[pythonico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)*, você pode utilizar o módulo nativo `itertools` para resolver o problema, mais especificamente a função `chain`, que faz exatamente o desejado (ou seja, já existe de forma nativa a função que é pedida para implementar).

```
from itertools import chain

listas = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7]]
resultado = list(chain(*listas))

print(resultado)
```

Será impresso `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. É importante notar que está solução utiliza a desconstrução de listas, com o operador `*` antecedendo o objeto e que o retorno de `chain` é um gerador, o que pode otimizar muito a solução, visto que não seria necessário ter uma cópia completa de todos os valores em memória.

Tenho ciência que o objetivo do exercício era justamente definir a função para aplicar os conceitos básicos, principalmente laços de repetição, mas acredito que estudar os conceitos aplicados para a presente solução são fundamentais e, por isso, resolvi postar a resposta.

Comment: Fui tentar entender o que o `chain()` faz e aí entrou em geradores e no comportamento meio mágico da palavra-chave `yield` e aí ficou avançado demais para mim (para um segundo dia de Python pelo menos)... sem falar que não entendi o operador `*`. O que eu entendi foi que `list()` converte um iterável para uma lista e que portanto `chain()` está retornando um iterável que percorre um a um os elementos da lista de listas (que é um iterável de iteráveis). É isso? Ah, e obrigado pela explicação :)

Comment: Exato. O gerador é um iterável com comportamento semelhante a um ponteiro de um *iterator*, se já está familiarizado com esses nomes. Em outras palavras, ele representa apenas um valor daquilo que está sendo iterado por vez. Mesmo que a lista possuísse milhões de valores, apenas um valor estaria armazenado em memória por vez, por isso a otimização. O operador `*` faz a desconstrução da lista, talvez seja mais fácil procurar por esses termos. Basicamente o que ele faz, nesse caso, cada item da lista em um parâmetro da função. Fazer `foo(*[x, y])` seria o mesmo que `foo(x, y)`.

Answer (score 4):

[`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)!

Python2:

```
listas = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6, 7]]
reduce(lambda prev, next: prev + next, listas)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Isso para listas de listas. Mas e para listas de listas de listas de listas...enfim, e para profundidade arbitrária? reduce recursivo!

```
lista = [[10], [20, 30], [20, [40, 50, 60, [79, [40, [59, 66, 77]]]]]]
def makeItFlat(lista):
    return [lista] if not isinstance(lista, list) else reduce(lambda x, y: makeItFlat(x) + makeItFlat(y), lista, [])
res = makeItFlat(lista)
print(res)

[10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 50, 60, 79, 40, 59, 66, 77]
```

Obs: em Python3 `reduce` se encontra no [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) module.

Answer (score 3):

As resposta atuais "deixam raso" listas de listas. Nesse caso, deixar raso é tudo na mesma profundidade. Objetos que antes estavam a uma profundidade de 2 listas ficam na profundidade de uma lista apenas. E se fosse possível informar uma profundidade arbitrária para "deixar raso"? Por exemplo, a lista profunda...

```
[1, 2, [[[3, [4], 5, [6, 7, [[8, 9], 10, [11]], 12], 13], 14], 15], 16, [17, [[[18]]], 19], 20]
```

... seria transformada nesta lista rasa:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

A ideia para resolver esse problema é ter uma função recursiva `shallowfy` (eu creio que "rasificar" não tem o mesmo impacto, então preferi usar a versão do nome em inglês mesmo) que faça o serviço. A entrada de `shallowfy` é uma lista e seu retorno é uma lista rasa. Seu funcionamento é o seguinte:

1. começo com uma lista vazia `shallow`
2. para cada elemento `el` da lista de entrada

   - se `el` não for uma lista, adiciona `el` no final de `shallow`
   - se `el` for uma lista, obtenho `shallow_el = shallowfy(el)`
   - adiciono todos os elementos de `shallow_el` no final de `shallow`
3. retorna `shallow`

A função fica assim:

```
def shallowfy(lista):
  shallow = []
  for el in lista:
    if (isinstance(el, list)):
      shallow_el = shallowfy(el)
      for subel in shallow_el:
        shallow.append(subel)
    else:
      shallow.append(el)
  return shallow
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/ctgae4).

Referências:

- Como identificar listas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192162/64969

Comment: Acho que o termo em inglês é "flatten".