# Como concatenar um vetor no outro elegantemente em ADVPL?

Tags: array, advpl

Tenho dois vetores de números, `aBuffer` e `aCandidato`. Dependendo de uma condição (externa ao vetor), preciso que `aBuffer` receba o conteúdo de `aCandidato` para trabalhar nele depois. `aBuffer` será usado por uma função que já está pronta para receber um vetor de números, portanto não gostaria de alterá-la.

Em Java, eu faria algo da seguinte maneira:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> aBuffer = ...;
ArrayList<Integer> aCandidato = ...;

...

if (condicaoMisteriosa()) {
  aBuffer.addAll(aCandidato);
}
```

Entretanto, em ADVPL, eu conheço apenas o `aadd`, que adiciona um elemento no final do vetor. O código que eu consigo fazer é:

```
local aBuffer := {}
local aCandidato := {}
local lCondicaoMisteriosa := ...
local i

...

If lCondicaoMisteriosa
  For i := 1 len(aCandidato)
    aadd(aBuffer, aCandidato[i])
  Next i
EndIf
```

O equivalente Java desse código seria:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> aBuffer = ...;
ArrayList<Integer> aCandidato = ...;

...

if (condicaoMisteriosa()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < aCandidato.size(); i++) {
    aBuffer.add(aCandidato.get(i));
  }
}
```

A alternativa de concatenar os vetor em um vetor intermediário, para então fazer o `flatten` (jogando o resultado em `aBuffer`) de modo semelhante a [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281993/64969) em Python, mas não vejo isso como sendo elegante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que isso faça o que deseja, elegante é relativo, mas parece mais simples e provavelmente mais rápido (em ADVPL sem testar eu nunca duvido que possa não ser):

```
tamanhoAtual = len(aBuffer)
asize(aBuffer, tamanhoAtual + len(aCandidato))
acopy(aCandidato, aBuffer, 1, len(aCandidato), tamanhoAtual + 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLConcatArray.prg).

Aumentei o tamanho do destino para caber os elementos do *array* fonte, aí invoquei a cópia da fonte desde o elemento 1 até o último e adicionei a partir do seguinte ao último elemento antes de ser aumentado. Se não aumentar o *array* dará erro, a não ser que já tivesse o espaço suficiente, mas estará correndo o risco de sobrepor algo que deveria continuar ali.